# Invoke PostGIS functions outside of the database? Need to force 3D in GeoDjango

Tags: python, postgis, 3d, geodjango, postgis-1.5

I'm looking to ensure that all geometries saved to the database are three-dimensional.  It's easy enough to do with a call to the database,

```
select ST_Force_3D( ST_GeomFromText( blah blah ) )
```

...but that means for every object saved in the database, we make two database calls.  Yuck!

Is there a simple way of invoking PostGIS functions without making a call to the database? We're using PostGIS 1.5 on top of Postgres 9.1 with GeoDjango on top of Python 2.7.

I've been working with [GEOSGeometry objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/geos/#django.contrib.gis.geos.GEOSGeometry), and they will tell you if your geometry is three-dimensional with the .hasz function, but I'm looking to FORCE everything to be three-dimensional without having to manually add a third dimension for every coordinate pair on every geometry we create.

Thanks!

Comment: Also, if you attempt to invoke `set_z(0)` on the GEOSGeometry object, it will throw an error:  `GEOSException: Cannot set Z on 2D Point.`

Answer (score 2):

I think you'll just have to make sure the points are 3d on creation, whenever that may be.
If you have the 2d points in a list it's easy to convert them.

```
points_2d = [Point(1,1), ...]

# create new points with z value
points_3d = [Point(pnt.x, pnt.y, 0) for pnt in points_2d]
```

Answer (score 2):

You have two options inside of Postgis. Either use the ST_Force_3D function in your INSERT statement or create a trigger for that table.

I have not run these on an actual database, so there may be some syntax issues, but the general idea should be fine.

Insert statement:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (the_geom) VALUES(ST_Force_3D(ST_GeomFromText('POINT (0 0)'))
)
```

Or Trigger:

```
-- General method that can be reused for other tables
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Force3DOnChange()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
BEGIN
    NEW.the_geom = ST_Force_3D(NEW.the_geom);

    RETURN NEW;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;

-- Specific Trigger function, must be created once per table
CREATE TRIGGER Force3DOn_mytable
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
  ON mytable
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE Force3DOnChange();
```